# Does it required to get licence for Itext pdf library for in house development?

Tags: java, itext

I want to use Itext library 5.2 for generation of report in pdf format for in-house software(Not for commercial use).
Does it required to buy license for it ?

Answer (score 2):

If it is really in-house, then [you are fine with the AGPL](http://www.affero.org/oagf.html#How_does_this_license_treat_commercial):

> Q: How does this license treat commercial enterprise use over
>   intranets and internal networks?
>
> A: Simply, if run internally to a
>   commercial company, then the company isn't required to release source
>   code back to the world. The license requires that if a user downloads
>   the source they have the right to make improvements and not release
>   these modifications. GNU GPL software in general addresses this issue
>   the same way. If an employee has access to the source and has the
>   right to make improvements, the commercial entity could probably view
>   this work as work for hire and owned by the company and not have to be
>   released outside.
>
> Q: Can a commercial entity remove the download source button in a
>   corporate intranet or internal networked environment?
>
> A: No. Anyone
>   who wants to use the software in a corporate intranet or internal
>   network, must leave the download source button but doesn't have to
>   make modifications available if not engaged in distribution. Anyone
>   engaged in distribution beyond their enterprise must leave the
>   download source button in place and make available the source for any
>   modifications through this button.
>
> Q: How do you define the enterprise networked together?
>
> A: Employees
>   connected through the employer's internal networks.

Also note that even commercial activities and distribution are fine, as long as you  open-source the rest of the program that uses iText.

If you let anyone outside your company access the application, even over a network, even for free, then you need to also give them a copy of the full source code (or get a commercial license).

Answer (score 1):

> Buying such a license is **mandatory as soon as you develop commercial
>   activities distributing the iText software inside your product or
>   deploying it on a network without disclosing the source code of your
>   own applications under the AGPL license**. These activities include:
>   offering paid services to customers as an ASP, serving PDFs on the fly
>   in the cloud or in a web application, shipping iText with a closed
>   source product.

So, I'd so no.

You may, however, need to define "in-house"